# Hosted django app on heroku, how would I go about creating images in models

Tags: django, heroku

Hi so I have an app where for every model object I create an image and so far I've made it so you manually create the images for multiple objects through an admin action. When I've run it locally it saves to the media folder but now I've deployed it to Heroku, so right now they're created but disappear into the ether. I want the user to be able to print the images so where do they go?

Comment: @Chris The thing is I don't want to store them anywhere, I want to press a button in the admin panel and then the images are created/downloaded and then printed. After that they shouldn't exist anymore.

Comment: So you go into the Django admin, do something in there, and that causes an image to be created that you then download to your local machine? You have code running on the server that creates a new image from some data source and sends it to your browser as a file?

Comment: @Chris that's the plan. I'm creating QR code images for a selected amount of entries and the only thing I want to do with them is print them out so I don't see a reason to store them but I guess I'll look at the other solution

Comment: Well maybe you have a relevant question, but it's hard to know for sure. Please read [ask] and provide as much information as you can. A [mcve] showing what you currently have would be helpful. And I'm still not clear about how "it saves to the media folder" locally maps to what you want in production.